# Better coffeescript workaround to load this node.js module

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I would like to use this node.js module https://github.com/mlin/node-assert-type

Based on documentation, to declare the module;

```
var ty = require("assert-type"); //https://github.com/mlin/node-assert-type
var T = ty.Assert;
```

In actual practice, this does not work. Some coffeescript error appears.

I have to make the following workaround;

```
var cs = require("coffee-script/register");//this line needed to require("assert-type")
var ty = require("assert-type"); //https://github.com/mlin/node-assert-type
var T = ty.Assert;
```

To use this module, I am forced to install coffeescript with `npm install -g coffeescript`.

Is there some way to omit the line `var cs = require("coffee-script/register");`? After all, the module itself is using coffeescript locally. Am I doing it the right way?

Is it a normal practice to add a line to load coffeescript for node.js modules which use coffee-script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not normal practice. I mean, it would be inevitable that coffeescript gets installed since it is a dependency but the user of the module should not worry about it.

I just took a quick look at the source code of the `assert-type` and this is what I found:

1. the project is 3 years old. That's a lot!
2. the `package.json` is listing `coffeescript` as a dependency BUT it is using `latest` instead of locking a version of coffeescript which is a terrible practice.
3. My guess is that what it changed was `coffeescript` module, that instead of needing `require('coffeescript')` you now need `require('coffeescript/register')`. (Take a look at the `index.js` in the repo)

Based on that I'd say it is fine that you write that line. A better option would be to make the changes in the `node-assert-type` repo and submit a PR with the fixes for #2 and #3.

Hope that helps.